# RestKit: RKObjectManager's postObject:mapResponseWith:delegate

Tags: http, rest, post, restkit

I want to send as an object as json

```
HTTP Headers: {
    "Content-Length" = 24;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
}
HTTP Body: {"userId":"5","mode":""}.
```

and get back a json

```
HTTP Headers: {
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
}
HTTP Body: {"insertCount":4,"offerCount":0,"favoriteOfferCount":0,"favoriteInsertCount":0}
```

and map it to an object, can anyone guide me as i'm getting many errors involving routers,object loader etc

I understand that i have to use RKObjectManager's postObject:mapResponseWith:delegate:

but configuring it is confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

never mind here's how i did it

```
@interface RestKitUtil :  NSObject <RKObjectLoaderDelegate,RKRequestDelegate>
-(void)postobj;
@end


@implementation RestKitUtil

-(void)postobj{

    RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network", RKLogLevelTrace);
   [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:@"http://10.6.10.121:80/CW_war"];

    RKObjectMapping* mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[CountResultVO class]];
    [mapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:
     @"offercount", @"offercount",
     @"insertCount", @"insertCount",
     @"favouriteOfferCount", @"favouriteOfferCount",
     @"favouriteInsertCount", @"favouriteInsertCount",
     nil];


   RKObjectRouter *router = [RKObjectManager sharedManager].router;
    [router routeClass:[BasicUserArgVo class] toResourcePath:@"/getMyOffersCount" forMethod:RKRequestMethodPOST];

    [RKObjectManager sharedManager].objectStore = [RKManagedObjectStore objectStoreWithStoreFilename:@"objStore.sqlite"];

    RKObjectMapping *listMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[BasicUserArgVo class]];    
    [listMapping mapKeyPath:@"userId" toAttribute:@"userId"];
    [listMapping mapKeyPath:@"mode" toAttribute:@"mode"];

    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider addObjectMapping:listMapping ];

    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setSerializationMapping:[listMapping inverseMapping] forClass:[BasicUserArgVo class]];

    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] setSerializationMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];
    //NSUTF8StringEncoding
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] setAcceptMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];


    BasicUserArgVo *bvo = [[BasicUserArgVo alloc] initWithUserId:5];

    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:bvo mapResponseWith:mapping delegate:self]; 
}


- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader*)objectLoader didLoadObjects:(NSArray*)objects {
    CountResultVO* cvo = [objects objectAtIndex:0];

    NSLog(@"values:%ld,%ld,%ld,%ld",[cvo offercount],[cvo insertCount],
          [cvo favouriteOfferCount],[cvo favouriteInsertCount] );
}

- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]];
    NSLog(@"log : %@",msg);    
}

@end
```